# What type of electronics soldering is this soldering flux used for?

Tags: soldering, flux

I usually use rosin flux for soldering or one with rosin core if the solder refuses to stick. I recently found this Goot BS-15 flux, but it says not applicable to PC boards. The label says hobby use soldering paste.

Unfortunately, the contents everything on the back of the container is in Japanese so I can't know for sure what this is intended to use for.

So,has anyone here come across this type of soldering flux and know what this might be used for?

[image: Front side]

[image: Rear side]

Comment: http://www.hapoin.com/en/flux/bs-10-15-850.htm Soldering paste for cables and large size terminals. BS-10/ 15 cannot be used on PCBs.

Comment: its an acid flux used for large connectors and cables vaseline 80-90% with zinc chloride and ammonium chloride as active ingredients.

Comment: @JohnD Thanks for the link. So, can this be used to solder those ring current terminals for high current battery terminals ?

Comment: Yes, that's within the intended application of this flux, but personally I would still use a non inorganic acid flux.  If you do use it make sure to clean it thoroughly afterward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is it says 'weak acid'. This is an acid-based flux, for soldering 'big stuff', cables onto terminals, and it should be suitable for plumbing as well. Clean the joint after soldering.

For PCBs, you should use a rosin-based flux. Most people use a cored solder, without using a separate flux.